# Angular Google Drive Api Response 400 by login

Tags: angular, google-api, google-drive-api, google-oauth, google-api-js-client

I want so use the Google Drive Api on Angular.

This is my login Request:

```
const DISCOVERY_DOCS = ['https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/drive/v3/rest'];
const SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive';
this.ngZone.run(() => {
  gapi.load('client:auth2', () => {
    return gapi.client.init({
        apiKey: API_KEY,
        clientId: CLIENT_ID,
        discoveryDocs: ['https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/drive/v3/rest'],
        scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive',
    }).then(() => {
        this.googleAuth = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
    });
  });
});
```

But I get a 400.

> zone-evergreen.js:171 Uncaught
> {error: {…}}
> error:
> code: 400
> errors: Array(1)
> 0:
> domain: "usageLimits"
> message: "Bad Request"
> reason: "keyInvalid"
> **proto**: Object
> length: 1
> **proto**: Array(0)
> message: "Bad Request"
> **proto**: Object
> **proto**: Object

I configured the google drive api.
I set the sourcelink to http://localhost:4200 and the forwarding link to http://localhost:4200.
What did I forgot?

Comment: try having a look at this https://developers.google.com/people/quickstart/js

Comment: Thanks, but this not helps me. I created a new project in the google api console. But I still get the message keyInvalid. But I don't know why the key is invalid

Comment: where did you get the key?

Comment: Does the API key correspond to the same project as the `CLIENT_ID`?